# How to add Stand-alone resource dictionaries in MAUI?

Tags: .net, xamarin, maui

I'm reading the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/resource-dictionaries) tutorial to create a stand-alone resource dictionary.

I created a file in the folder **Resources/Styles** called "MyStyle.xaml" as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonDataTemplate">
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid RowSpacing="6"
                  ColumnSpacing="6">
                ...
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I edited the file App.xaml as follows :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/MyStyle.xaml" /> <!-- Here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And in a page I added the dictionary:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="PageName"
             Title="PageName">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyStyle.xaml" /> <!-- Here -->
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <!-- something -->                      
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I almost copy pasted the code in the official documentation page. But when compiling I'm getting the error:

```
XFC0124 Resource "MyStyle.xaml" not found.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you only add it to the MergedDictionaries in the Application.Resources, not at the page level.

Comment: @Andrew thanks for your comment. What should I add please ? and where ?

Answer (score 0):

Just as Andrew said,you can try to add the following code in your page :

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >

        <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/MyStyle.xaml" />

    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Andrew said in comments you need MergedDictionaries

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/MyStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the folder is not in same level as mentioned in comments. I just added a slash in the front of the path.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Styles/MyStyle.xaml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, If you add a resource file at the application level you don't need to add it again at the page level. Just reference the resource in your style.

Second, Check that your BuildAction is set to MauiXaml

Example:

MyStyle.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xaml-comp compile="true" ?>
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml">
    <Color x:Key="YellowColor"> Yellow</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

App.xaml

```xml
 <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <life:LifeDesignButtons />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/MyStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
```

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Label TextColor="{StaticResource YellowColor}" Text="Hello"/>
```